# How to close nc port in Debian 9?

Tags: linux, services, netstat, port

I am struggling to close these ports which seem to be backdoors -- or at least I have never opened and used them. How can I close or shutdown nc and close these ports?

```
netstat -lntup | grep nc
```

[image: netstat output]

```
ps-ef
```

[image: ps -ef output]

Comment: You may able to use the PPID of the `nc` processes to identify where the processes are coming from. Perhaps a runaway script?

Comment: thanks, I am new linux OS, should I check process id?

Comment: Yes, you can run `ps -ef|grep nc` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel, I haved added the output for ps

Comment: I can see the update, but [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). The third column in that output is the parent PID of a process. You can examine parent process using `ps -p PID`. For example, the first nc process (925) has process 922 as its parent, which again has 921 as its parent. Keep tracing the process parent and see if you can get any useful information.

Comment: In the 2nd top most parent I find 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f which is a kind of job running or backdoor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86162/discussion-between-haxiel-and-arh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After further investigation through chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86162/discussion-between-haxiel-and-arh), the problem was identified with a specific crontab on OP's system. This was identified using the parent PID of the `nc` process, which showed the following connection:

`nc -l -p 45454 -e /usr/sbin/link` -> `/bin/sh -c nc -l -p 45454 -e /usr/sbin/link` -> `/usr/sbin/CRON -f`

The user account associated with the `nc` process was named 'link', and had a crontab associated with it. This crontab contained a cron job with the same `nc` command, scheduled to be run every minute. Since the `nc` command had been specified to listen indefinitely, new `nc` processes were being created every minute.

The issue was resolved by commenting out the specific entry in the crontab file.

Comment: That chain of processes has some suspicious properties: `/usr/sbin/link` is **not** a standard command, although the name closely resembles the standard `/usr/bin/link`, which would be nonsensical to call from `nc` like that. Likewise, `/usr/sbin/CRON` in all-caps is different from the standard `/usr/sbin/cron`. You should see if  `/usr/sbin/link` and/or `/usr/sbin/CRON` actually exist, and get them analyzed if they do exist; you may find that they are parts of an intruder's toolkit. There might be an innocent explanation too, but it is possible that someone has (clumsily) hacked this system.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for the useful info. I'll point OP to your comment from chat.